# View Multiple localhost Dev website projects from VM Virtual Box to test IE compatibility

Tags: internet-explorer, localhost, fedora, virtualbox

I'm running Fedora 14 and I have various web-development projects in my localHost.

I have installed VM VirtualBox and installed windowsXP to test Internet Explorer compatibility issues of my projects.

I can access the 1st localhost website project by typing the IP address of my laptop on the VirtualBox IE8 but I don't know how to access the other projects under Fedora localhost.

I looked on the internet but I find it confusing and I keep getting stuck.

Here's what I have:

**1 -> sudo gedit /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain   localhost.localdomain   localhost   localhost4  www.smile   www.intranet    www.etrack  manosLocal  www.box 
::1 localhost.localdomain   localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6  localhost   manosLocal
```

**2 -> sudo gedit /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin root@localhost     
     ServerName www.smile
     ServerAlias www.smile
     DocumentRoot /repos/smile/trunk
     ErrorLog /srv/www/logs/smile_error.log 
     CustomLog /srv/www/logs/smile_access.log combined <br />
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin root@localhost          
     ServerName www.intranet
     ServerAlias www.intranet
     DocumentRoot /repos/intranet/trunk
     ErrorLog /srv/www/logs/intranet_error.log       
     CustomLog /srv/www/logs/intranet_access.log combined <br />
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin root@localhost     
     ServerName www.etrack
     ServerAlias www.etrack
     DocumentRoot /repos/etrack/trunk
     ErrorLog /srv/www/logs/etrack_error.log 
     CustomLog /srv/www/logs/etrack_access.log combined <br />
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin root@localhost     
     ServerName www.box
     ServerAlias www.box
     DocumentRoot /repos/box/trunk
     ErrorLog /srv/www/logs/box_error.log 
     CustomLog /srv/www/logs/box_access.log combined <br />
</VirtualHost>
```

My Laptop IP address is: 
**ifconfig** -> `inet addr:192.168.1.57`

When I start my VirtualBox-WindowsXP and type this IP address in IE8 I can access the `www.smile` website of my Fedora LocalHost.
If I change the order of the VirtualHosts and restart the HTTPD service then I can also access whichever Localhost I put first in the order.

I want to be able to access all the VirtualHosts of my Fedora Localhost at the same time but I don't know how to do it.

Any help would be truly appreciated.
Manos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I just had to configure the host file in the Windows XP of the virtualBox.

```
c:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Then replace the default `127.0.0.1    localhost`

with the `ifconfig` IP address along with all my virtualHosts

```
192.168.1.57    localhost    www.smile    www.intranet    www.box    www.etrack
```

Save the file restart Internet Explorer and type any of the above addresses :-)
Done!

Comment: Mark your question as answered then (tick the "v" next to your self-response).